# Regex too complex for JSON response from External System

Tags: apex, integration, json, regular-expressions

I am getting "Regex too complicated" error when i am trying to make a callout with "getPassenger" method .to me, it seems the JSON response is big enough.I need to call this service once per booking(queryParam)queryParam and process it one at a time.

[image]

```
 List<String> currentBookingFilter;
        String departureStation;
        String arrivalStation;
        String departureDate;
        String arrivalDate;
        try {
            List<String> splitBookingFilters = bookings.split(',');
            List<IRR_MOD_PassengerInfo> passengerInfos = new List<IRR_MOD_PassengerInfo>();
            for (String bookingFilter : splitBookingFilters) {
                if (String.isBlank(bookingFilter)) continue;
                currentBookingFilter = bookingFilter.split('!');
                departureStation = currentBookingFilter.size() >= 1 && String.isNotBlank(currentBookingFilter[0]) ? currentBookingFilter[0] : null ;
                arrivalStation = currentBookingFilter.size() >= 2 && String.isNotBlank(currentBookingFilter[1]) ? currentBookingFilter[1] : null;
                departureDate = currentBookingFilter[2] ;
                arrivalDate = currentBookingFilter[3] ;
                passengerInfos.addAll(externalService.getPassenger(departureStation,arrivalStation,departureDate,arrivalDate));
            }
```

getPassenger calls to getBookingDetails where I delete any null values for queryparams. Any immediate help is appreciated.

```
private List<X_Booking> getBookingDetails(String departureStation, String arrivalStation,String fromTimeUTC,String toTimeUTC) {
        Map<String, String> queryParams = new Map<String, String>{
            'departureStation' => departureStation,
            'arrivalStation' => arrivalStation,
            'fromTimeUTC' => fromTimeUTC,
            'toTimeUTC' => toTimeUTC
            
        };

        C_X.IntegrationResponse responseObject = integrationExecutor
                .executeRequest(ENDPOINT, C_X.Method.GET, null, queryParams);
        if (responseObject.statusCode >= 300 || responseObject.statusCode<200) {
            throwException(responseObject);
        }
  
        List<Booking> Bookings = Booking.parseArray(responseObject.responseBody);
        return tBookings;
```

Here is my Deserializer method.

```
public Object deserialize(String jsonString) {
        try {
            ...........
                    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(DOUBLE_QUOTE + field + REGULAR_EXPRESSION, DOUBLE_QUOTE + replacement + DOUBLE_QUOTE_COLON);
                }
            }

            return m_apexType == null ? JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString) : JSON.deserialize(jsonString, m_apexType);
```

Comment: I'm guessing your issue is in the `bookings.split(',')` (or perhaps the `bookingFilter.split('!')`) statement. JSON uses commas to separate properties and array items. It seems likely that this splitting would not be appropriate if you have JSON with any sort of complexity. Is there a reason you are not using `JSON.deserialize` or `JSON.deserializeUntyped` here?

Comment: Oh..No that splitting is not for JSON response. As you see in the screenshot, there are four input fields which has to be passed as query parameters in the callout. so I prepare a bookingId as: "return `${departureStation}!${arrivalStation}!${departureDate}!${arrivalDate}`; "which i later segregate into separate parameters to be passed(bookingFilter.split('!')) ).

Comment: ```bookings.split(',') ```` is nothing but separating multiple bookkings into individual bookings. E.g Bookings[{MAD!BCN!20210216!20210217},DFW!OU!20210216!2021021,...] so split them(bookings.split(',') ) into MAD!BCN!20210216!20210217 and DFW!OU!20210216!2021021 and then later use bookingFilter.split('!') to split them into arrival station= DFW, depart station = HOU .....

Comment: So where is your JSON? The content of your question doesn't reflect what you said in the title... Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/334280/edit) the question to clarify.

Comment: The method ParseAray in the line List<Booking> Bookings = Booking.parseArray(responseObject.responseBody) calls JSONdeserializer method.I updated the question with my JSON deserializer method.

Comment: Why are you mutating the JSON string prior to deserialization? Is it not valid JSON incoming? That pattern often suggests to me that something else is wrong in the system.

Comment: We are using FFLIB and this is one of the methods from the class ffhttp_JsonDeserializer which allow JSON strings to be deserialized into a given type.